# Full sentence "{year} Moderator election" is needed for localization purpose

Tags: bug, status-completed, election, localization

Currently the title on the moderator election page has the form `{year} Moderator election`. But it seems that that form is concatenated on server side from two parts: `{year}` and the rest text. [E.g.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/election/5):

> [image: Moderator election]

However, listing the year before the words "moderator election" is incorrect in Russian.

For the purpose of correct localization the full sentence "{year} Moderator election" is needed here to correctly translate the page title for community moderator election.

The needed sentence is [exist](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/8822), but used only for a part of html tag `<title>` for the same page.

Could this please be used to the page title as showed on the screenshot above?

Comment: Interestingly, `$Year$ Moderator Election` is already a string in Traducir (as you point out), because that whole phrase is set as translatable in most cases where this string appears (including, as you've pointed out, in the page title for this election page)... The only place where that's not the case seems to be this `<h1>` element that appears on the election page itself.

Comment: @V2Blast btw can we make that header clickable in the same way as it done for Q title (i.e. with a target link to the same page)? Maybe it's worth separate FR.

Comment: Yeah, I'd suggest posting that as a separate feature request (if it isn't one already). That said, I don't see a particular *need* to make that header clickable, so you should explain your reasoning if you do make that post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I fixed this issue! The string should now be actually translatable (and already translated, as V2Blast mentions above). Thanks for the report.

Comment: Seems like we have to wait for a new build to check the translation [here](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/election/5).

Comment: Yep - build just finished and looks like it's fixed now!